# как выбирать по 10 элементов из таблицы

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, pdo, redbeanphp

как ме брать по 10 элементов из таблицы, сначала 10 потом следующие 10, ещё должны выбираться сначала новые.

Таблица  `id | title | text | time`

использую redbeanphp, могу получить все элементы так

```
    $posts = R::findAll('posts', 'ORDER BY `time` DESC');
```

можно ли как-то дополнить чтобы получать по 10 элементов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала узнайте, сколько постов. Потом получайте по 10 с помощью LIMIT:
1) ... LIMIT 0, 10
2) ... LIMIT 10, 10
3) ... LIMIT 20, 10
и т.д.

Синтаксис следующий: первое число - номер строки(начинается с 0), второе число - кол-во строк на выборку