# Как отобрать строки после определенной найденной строки?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица со столбцом id. Мне нужно получить строки после строки с id='0123456'. Что нужно прицепить к запросу?

Comment: С id >= 123456?

Comment: Я условно такой id написал - там будут последовательности символов

Comment: А как это "после"?

Comment: Чего вы пытаетесь добиться?

Comment: Порядок строк в бд - чисто условный. На это нельзя опираться

Comment: Скажем, есть три строки в таблице.
Идет запрос с id второй строки - я должен получить в ответ часть таблицы после нее, то есть, только третью строку

Comment: `после нее` зависит от сортировки строк в конкретном запросе из этой таблицы

Comment: Поясните более конкретно, какую задачу вы решаете? Зачем вам это нужно?

Comment: Я бы хотел, чтобы каждый запрос подбирал следующую "порцию" таблицы относительно последнего запроса.
То есть, если в таблице 100 строк, то каждый запрос берет следующие 20 относительно последней взятой строки.
Предположил, что есть условный оператор, который бы заставлял запрос игнорировать все совпадения до определенного совпадения.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1126213/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be-10-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b/1126221#1126221

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [как выбирать по 10 элементов из таблицы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1126213/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be-10-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b)